# H2 not letting me insert data in bulk

Tags: sql, h2

So I've prepared `INSERT` statements to add data in bulk to my database (for performance testing) but every time I run a fairly large statement (about 100,000 data points), it just crashes instantly on me.

[image]

Sometimes, it gives me a "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Whitelabel error page" error. Really not sure what to do. Is it just not possible to add a ton of data through the H2 webpage like that ?

Comment: The `INSERT` statements work fine if I do them in intervals of about 10,000 (instead of the full 100,000). Not sure why.

Comment: Probably Java memory settings? Can you run h2 in a way it displays the stack trace?

Comment: http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html?highlight=limit&search=Limit#firstFound